# how to make tables clickable html

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

I have this table with buttons:

```
        <tr>
            <td><button type="text" name = "class_name" value=<?=$class["class_name"]?>><?=$class["class_name"]?></button></th>
            <td><?=$class["class_id"] ?></th>
        </tr>

     <?php endforeach ?>
```

I'm passing the selected school class(the button) to another file to update a database. But the table and the buttons just look really bad.

I thought that if instead the whole table was clickable it would look nicer, and maybe giving it some light color inside and then adding a background image would make the page acceptable.

Any help on how to do that?

PS: I have seen this done with JavaScript but I don't know much of it and I'm trying to keep this simple with html and css.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Clarification: My question is; how can i make my button look nicer while still being able to use it as a POST form?

Comment: create a snippet with the table's html output, we can't run your php code

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You ask us to create a nice looking button for your table?

Answer (score 1):

Go to [button.cm](https://buttons.cm/) and it will create the html and VML needed to give you a fully clickable button in HTML/CSS and not just as an image.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle" width="33%" style="background-color:#6483c1; border:1px solid #44619a; border-radius:2px;">
      <a href="http:class_name.html" target="_blank" style="padding:20px 10px;display:block;color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;"><font size="3" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#ffffff"><b>class_name</b></font></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, although this does create a nice looking table, I'm struggling to use it as a form post with php.

Comment: can you create a fiddle so i can have a look your error.